# Duplicating iOS 7 syle UISegmentControl using jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, ios7

I am a newbie to web technologies and currently working on a hybrid mobile app,I would like to duplicate iOS's UISegmentControl in the app. Something like this,

[image]

but I tried to do this using HTML and CSS and ended up doing this,

[image]

The tint color would be this #ff8400.

```
     <div id="itemColorSizeToogleDiv">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">Size</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Color</label>

        </fieldset>
        </div>

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4JFS6/
```

is what I have tried so far.I know it is possible to do the exact same thing but I am stuck up, any help is appreciated.

Comment: so what is your problem? The color and corners?

Comment: The colors, corners, selection color, deselected color, border color, border width.